# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to lookup info for package

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run my app by android studio some times I get this error and app didn't run:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: ir.android_studio.ati_school_student, PID: 2860
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to lookup info for package ir.android_studio.ati_school_student
            at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1958)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:651)
            at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getStringForUser(Settings.java:2099)
            at android.provider.Settings$Global.getStringForUser(Settings.java:12212)
            at android.provider.Settings$Global.getString(Settings.java:12201)
            at android.provider.Settings$Global.getInt(Settings.java:12380)
            at android.os.GraphicsEnvironment.setupGpuLayers(GraphicsEnvironment.java:95)
            at android.os.GraphicsEnvironment.setup(GraphicsEnvironment.java:56)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.setupGraphicsSupport(ActivityThread.java:5475)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5756)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
         Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
            at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.getCallingApplicationInfoOrThrow(SettingsProvider.java:1741)
            at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceSettingReadable(SettingsProvider.java:1714)
            at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.getGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:964)
            at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:384)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:403)
```

What is this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: No I didn't . I just run it again . I think this is a bug in android studio 4